# Is there a way to "reload notebook from disk" automatically and periodically without any pop up on Jupiter-lab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, gcp-notebook

I would like to collaborate with some people on notebooks using jupyterlab.

What I have done so far is to create an instance on GCP and gives them an address to connect to the JupiterLab running in this instance. This works well and we can change simultaneously the notebook.

However, I would like to be able to see in live the changes made by the others without having to reload the notebook every time with the button "Reload Notebook from Disk". So I was wondering if there was a way to reload a notebook from disk periodically to be able to see the changes made by the others ? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. This is a limitation of Jupyter Lab and would need to be fixed either by them or by a Jupyter Lab plugin that someone creates

Comment: This is now possible according to this discussion https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/discussions/14516

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible using jupyter-lab collaborative mode, but you have to install the `jupyter_collaboration` package first:

```bash
$ pip install jupyterlab_collaboration
$ jupyter-lab --collaborative
```