# Auto reloading jupyter notebook when file changed on disk

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, ipython

I'd like to edit jupyter notebooks using an IDE (pycharm) for the autocomplete functionality. But pycharm isn't very good at executing / previewing the results, so I'd like to keep the notebook open in the browser and automatically reload whenever the file changes on disk.

Ideal workflow:

- Edit code in Pycharm
- Automatically see updated code in browser and hit ctrl + enter to see output

Current workflow:

- Edit code in Pycharm
- Manually hit refresh in browser, sometimes see a browser warning and have to click a confirmation to reload, then see changes and hit ctrl + enter

I've tried:

```
#%load_ext autoreload
#%autoreload 2
```

but it doesn't seem to do much.

Sometimes the browser detects that the file has changed (usually several seconds after its changed), but I then have to click two seperate confirmation dialogs to actually refresh the page.

Any ideas how it could just reload automatically whenever it changes on disc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to "reload notebook from disk" automatically and periodically without any pop up on Jupiter-lab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56112948/is-there-a-way-to-reload-notebook-from-disk-automatically-and-periodically-wit)

Comment: This is now possible using collaborative, see discussion on GitHub https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/discussions/14516

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a PyCharm user ,
but you my look for a solution inside PyCharm, something like "preview" ...

Other approach you may use somehing similar to it https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/easy-auto-refresh/aabcgdmkeabbnleenpncegpcngjpnjkc?hl=pt-BR
on your browser.

I dont think the answer relies on JuPyter.